# how to add a parent table value CGridView using yii

Tags: database, activerecord, yii, yii-components

Currently my CGridView gives following result.

http://imageshack.us/a/img821/2391/44264318.png

Here City is actually CityID From a parent table. City table has one-to-many relationship with Campus table. I want to show city.cityname instead of city.cityid from parent table. Can someone help please.
Database structure is as

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/845/82338990.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change that column to

```
array (
'name'=>'mycol
'value'=>'$data->city->cityname',
);
```

where city is a relation name, and cityname is an attribute from the linked class.

To sort see this article http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

Comment: Thanks it is showing values with this code <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'id'=>'campus-grid',
 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
 'columns'=>array(
  'CampusName',
  array(
  'name'=>'CityID',
  'value'=>'$data->city->CityName',
  ),

  'Description',
  array(
   'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
  ),
 ),
)); ?>   But it is not searching records based on CityName. Is is searching records based on CityID.

Comment: Thanks above article helped me.

Answer (score 0):

in your grid columns use:

```
array (
   ...
   'city.cityname',
   ... other columns...
);
```